# Restart stream if no response

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-stream, twitter-streaming-api, playframework-2.5

I'm using twitter stream api and after 2 minutes twitter stops sending me tweets, but if I stop and rerun app then again sends me data. So I want If I don't receive response after 30 seconds I want to restart stream.

My code

```
ws.url(url)
  .sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey,requestToken))
  .withQueryString(("track",keywordsString))
  .withMethod("POST")
  .stream()
  .map { response =>
    Logger.info(keywordsString+" : "+response.headers.status)
    if(response.headers.status == 200){
      response.body
        //.keepAlive ?
        //.idleTimeout ?
        .via(sharedKillSwitch.flow)
        .scan("")((acc, curr) => if (acc.contains("\r\n")) curr.utf8String else acc + curr.utf8String)
        .filter(_.contains("\r\n"))
        .map ( json => Try(parse(json).extract[Tweet]) )
        .runForeach {
          case Success(tweet) => mentionActor ! StreamPair(keywords,tweet)
          case Failure(e) => Logger.info("Failure: "+e.getMessage)
        }
    }
    if(response.headers.status.toString.startsWith("4")){
      Logger.info("Response 4XX : "+response.headers.status)
      response.body
        .via(sharedKillSwitch.flow)
        .scan("")((acc, curr) => if (acc.contains("\r\n")) curr.utf8String else acc + curr.utf8String)
        .filter(_.contains("\r\n"))
        .map ( json => json )
        .runForeach{
          case error: String =>
            Logger.info("error: "+error)
            this.stopStream()
            streamRestartActor ! StartStream(keywords,keywordsString)
        }
    }
  }
```

SOLUTION:

```
 ws.url(url)
  .sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey,requestToken))
  .withQueryString(("track",keywordsString))
  .withMethod("POST")
  .stream()
  .map { response =>
    Logger.info(keywordsString+" : "+response.headers.status)
    if(response.headers.status == 200){
      response.body
        .via(sharedKillSwitch.flow)
        .idleTimeout(30.seconds) //this
        .scan("")((acc, curr) => if (acc.contains("\r\n")) curr.utf8String else acc + curr.utf8String)
        .filter(_.contains("\r\n"))
        .map ( json => Try(parse(json).extract[Tweet]) )
        .runForeach {
          case Success(tweet) => mentionActor ! StreamPair(keywords,tweet)
          case Failure(e) => Logger.info("Failure: "+e.getMessage)
        }
        .onComplete { //this
          case Success(_) =>
            Logger.info("Done")
            this.stopStream()
            Thread.sleep(time)
            streamRestartActor ! StartStream(keywords,keywordsString)
          case Failure(e) =>
            Logger.info("Failed with "+e.getMessage)
            this.stopStream()
            Thread.sleep(time)
            streamRestartActor ! StartStream(keywords,keywordsString)
        }
    }
    if(response.headers.status.toString.startsWith("4")){
      Logger.info("Response 4XX : "+response.headers.status)
      response.body
        .via(sharedKillSwitch.flow)
        .scan("")((acc, curr) => if (acc.contains("\r\n")) curr.utf8String else acc + curr.utf8String)
        .filter(_.contains("\r\n"))
        .map ( json => json )
        .runForeach{
          case error: String =>
            Logger.info("error: "+error)
            this.stopStream()
            Thread.sleep(time)
            streamRestartActor ! StartStream(keywords,keywordsString)
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think showing the declaration of `ws` would be helpful.

Comment: that is WSClient https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS . I have solved this with idleTimeout(time) and onComplete